# Strange double subtraction result in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double

I'm aware of the inaccuracies of floating point operations but the results of the below code seem rather odd to be. Can anybody please explain it?

This is with .NET Framework 4.8 on Windows 10. The code was compiled with csc.exe and no other options.

Thanks!

```
using System;
class Test {

    public static void Main() {
        double f1 = Math.Exp(Math.Log(10));
        double f2 = 10;
        double f3 = 10;

        Console.WriteLine(f1);
        Console.WriteLine(f1-10.0);
        Console.WriteLine(f2-f3);
    }
}
```

The results are:

```
10
1.77635683940025E-15
0
```

An inspection of the generated code with ildasm shows:

```
  IL_0001:  ldc.r8     10.
  IL_000a:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Log(float64)
  IL_000f:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Exp(float64)
  IL_0014:  stloc.0
  IL_0015:  ldc.r8     10.
  IL_001e:  stloc.1
  IL_001f:  ldc.r8     10.
  IL_0028:  stloc.2
  IL_0029:  ldloc.0
  IL_002a:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(float64)
  IL_002f:  nop
  IL_0030:  ldloc.0
  IL_0031:  ldc.r8     10.
  IL_003a:  sub
  IL_003b:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(float64)
  IL_0040:  nop
  IL_0041:  ldloc.1
  IL_0042:  ldloc.2
  IL_0043:  sub
  IL_0044:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(float64)
```

I can't see any obvious explanation for the difference so what might I be missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Interresting would also be what `f1 - f2` would evaluate to.

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23782/why-is-exp-lnx-x-neq0-in-floating-point-arithmetic

Comment: Thanks. That does explain things and I hadn't considered looking on scicomp. Very odd though but manageable.

Comment: It's the presented precision that is in fault. If you change to [.net 5](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VApohb) you will have `10.000000000000002` or in [4.7.2+](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yw7Fz6) you can use `Console.WriteLine("{0:R}",f1);` will give you the same result.
If you want to see the real value Jon Skeet double converter [here*](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) has a To ExactString method that can do that for you like https://dotnetfiddle.net/S5y8Bz.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "G" format specifier (precision of 15 for doubles).

*Update: In .NET Framework (as opposed to .Net Core/5) G or G15 doesn't help. We need to use `R` ([round-trip format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#round-trip-format-specifier-r))*.

```
Console.WriteLine(f1.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine((f1-10.0).ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine((f2-f3).ToString("R"));
```

This produces:

```
10.000000000000002
1.7763568394002505E-15
0
```

Since `1.77635683940025E-15` rounds up to `0.000000000000002` it all seems fine.

Comment: `G15` doesn't work because it's `G17`.While G will work in .net5, G15 is consitent on both .net4 and .net5  https://dotnetfiddle.net/cCEbHE.  (off topics comment: "correlation does not imply causation", even if it happended the exact sec I commented)